# System.StringException: Unexpected end of expression

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, compile-error

**Error:**

> Line: 3, Column: 1 System.StringException: Unexpected end of expression.

**Class:**

```
public class OppSchedule implements schedulable{
    public void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
        List<Opportunity> opp=[select id,name,stageName from Opportunity where stageName='closedWon'];
        for(Opportunity o:opp){
            if(o.stageName =='closedWon'){
                delete o;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Anonymous Script:**

```
System.Schedule('mj','0 0-5 13 ?  * ',new OppSchedule());
```

Comment: You should never ever include DML Statements in a loop. Here, your `if` statement is also completely redundant. Simply call `delete [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE ...]`.

Answer (score 7):

cron expressions have 6 or 7 parts, and you've only included five.

From the [Apex Scheduler documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm) (emphasis mine)

> The System.Schedule method takes three arguments: a name for the job, **an expression used to represent the time and date the job is scheduled to run**, and the name of the class. **This expression has the following syntax:**
>
> ```
> Seconds Minutes Hours Day_of_month Month Day_of_week Optional_year
> ```

The seventh part of the format is (as the slot name implies) optional, but using a dash to specify a range is only valid for the `Day_of_month`, `Month`, `Day_of_week`, and `Optional_year` parts.

The root of the issue is that you've tried to use a range for the `minutes` part.